# NodeJS + MySQL, can't access DB from application while INSERT but can access from terminal

Tags: mysql, sql-server, node.js, database

I have a big data array which I try to insert into my database, then delete an old table and rename the new one. To do it faster I use TRANSACTION (it doesn't affect my problem, I tried without it) and make every MySQL query inside async.each function. In the callback of this async.each I do COMMIT (for transaction), deleting and renaming.

Usually I have 100000 or more rows to insert. If I use "SELECT COUNT(*)" in terminal I can see these rows insert quite slowly but somehow the process ends immediately when 1/4 of rows was inserted. Then I got a full table in one moment. I don't know why it happens, I'm OK with that but maybe this is the reason of my problem.

So this is my problem: I have no access to DB from Node while it makes inserting. But I still can access it from terminal where I can count rows, see a tables etc. If Node calls some other function with mysql query, this query will just wait until that big insert will end. 
It's like Node code works in parallel but mysql queries work in just one thread. How can I fix this?

```
    exports.insertSubscribers = function(data, db_name, done){
        state.pool.query('START TRANSACTION');
        async.each(data, function(row, cb){
            state.pool.query('INSERT INTO new_' + db_name + ' (id, first_name, last_name, sex, city, country, photo_200) VALUES (' + "'" + row.id + "', " + "'" + row.first_name + "', " + "'" + row.last_name + "', " + "'" + row.sex + "', " + "'" + JSON.stringify(row.city) + "', " + "'" + JSON.stringify(row.country) + "', " + "'" + row.photo_200 + "'" + ')', cb);
        }, end_transaction);

        function end_transaction(){
            state.pool.query('COMMIT', function(err){
                if(err) return done(err);
                state.pool.query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'' + db_name + '\'', function(err, result){
                    if(result.length != 0){
                        state.pool.query('DROP TABLE ' + db_name, function(err){
                            if(err) return done(err);
                            state.pool.query('RENAME TABLE new_' + db_name + ' TO ' + db_name, function(err){
                                if(err) return done(err);
                            });
                        });
                    }else{
                        state.pool.query('RENAME TABLE new_' + db_name + ' TO ' + db_name, function(err){
                            if(err) return done(err);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL by design only allows at most one query per connection at any given time. So what some MySQL drivers/modules do is to simply maintain an in-memory queue that is used when additional queries are made while another is in progress.

One possible workaround for this is to use multiple connections in a pool (the `mysql` and `mysql2` modules have built-in pooling support for example) so that you can execute more queries in parallel.

Comment: So when I need to write a new data I have to create a new pool (with the same user) and write it from this pool? And when all data is written I have to close this pool, right? I think you may be right because now I use just one pool which is created when server starts